# Iteratively computing scipy matrix multiplication

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse_csr matrix c and d:

```
a=np.array([[1,0,1],[0,0,1]])
b=np.array([[1,1,1],[1,0,1],[0,0,0]])

c=sparse.csr_matrix(a)
d=sparse.csr_matrix(b)
```

I am iteratively multiplying c and d like this:

```
for j in range(3):
    c_new = d.dot(c.T).T
    c = c_new
```

I observed the `type(c)` is `<class 'scipy.sparse.csc.csc_matrix'>`. This slows down to do matrix computation for large matrix inside every iteration. Is there any way to speed up the process keeping the "csr" format.

Comment: So you are doing `(d * d * d * c.T).T`; repeated or chained matrix products, not iterative ones.  Matrix multiplication is a strong point for sparse matrices - for large, really sparse ones.  For small relatively dense ones it will slower than dense array `dot`.

Comment: Do you want just 3 repetitions, or some variable number.  It looks a bit like a matrix power calculation.   `d**3 * c.T`; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28702416/matrix-power-for-sparse-matrix-in-python

Comment: For repeated dense matrix product see https://stackoverflow.com/q/48801371/901925